# Is order of script onload and window.onload well defined when the script is a DOM node created dynamically from a loaded script?

Tags: javascript, html, callback

File `loader.js`:

```
function main()
{
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    var script = window.document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js'
    script.onload = function () { console.log('script loaded') }
    window.onload = function () { console.log('window loaded') }
    window.document.head.appendChild(script)
  } else {
    console.log('window not available yet')
  }
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  exports.main = main
}

main()
```

File `window.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Console output when I open this HTML page:

```
script loaded
window loaded
```

My question:

In the above code, is it guaranteed that the script onload event always fires before the window onload?

Comment: Also, see this follow-up question about JSDOM: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53084715/1175080. In this question, we see that JSDOM fires the `window.onload` event *before* the `script.onload` event. So I am trying to figure if an authoritative standard (such as a W3C document) that requires that the `window.onload` event should fire after the `script.onload` event if a script element is added to the DOM as part of window loading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the output you see is guaranteed, because the `load` event is fired "when a resource *and its dependent resources* have finished loading." The `window` will not be fully loaded until *every* element with something to download is downloaded and ready, including scripts and images. So, the `<script>` has to load before the `window` loads.

The fact that there's a script which is created dynamically won't have an effect (assuming that `main` is called before the window is fully loaded, like in your code) - once inserted into the DOM, it's now something the window depends on, and so must `load` before the window does.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have now a follow up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084715/script-onload-happens-after-window-onload-in-jsdom where the opposite behaviour (window onload before script onload) occurs in JSDOM.