# Script onload happens after window onload in JSDOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, onload, jsdom

This is a new question arising from what I learnt in: [Is order of script onload and window.onload well defined when the script is a DOM node created dynamically from a loaded script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075705/is-order-of-script-onload-and-window-onload-well-defined-when-the-script-is-a-do)

In the previous question we learnt that when a window is loading scripts, any scripts (the one directly loaded as well as the ones dynamically being loaded by the script) would finish loading first and only after that the `window.onload` will fire.

But JSDOM seems to be behaving differently.

Here is the `loader.js` script which is same as the one in the previous question:

```
function main()
{
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    var script = window.document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.core.min.js'
    script.onload = function () { console.log('script loaded') }
    window.onload = function () { console.log('window loaded') }
    window.document.head.appendChild(script)
  } else {
    console.log('window not available yet')
  }
}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
  exports.main = main
}

main()
```

Here is the driver code that pretends to be a fake window via JSDOM.

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')
var loader = require('./loader.js')

var html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="loader.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Test</div>
  </body>
</html>`

global.window = new jsdom.JSDOM(html, { runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" }).window
```

This is the output:

```
$ node fakewindow.js 
window not available yet
window loaded
script loaded
```

The `window.onload` event fired before the `script.onload` event fire. Why did JSDOM consider the window loaded even when a dynamic script loaded by a script directly included in the HTML hadn't loaded yet? Is this a bug in JSDOM or is this behavior allowed by relevant W3C standards?

Comment: I guess the window loaded before you attached the script tag? JSDOM probably loads the window really fast since it just has to construct and not actually render/paint anything

Comment: @schu34 If you see the second code block, the one that creates `new jsdom.JSDOM` in its last line, you'll find that it requires the JSDOM to load a window with an HTML code and the HTML code dynamically adds a `SCRIPT` element to the DOM. As per the question and answer at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53075705/1175080, it appears that this should cause the `window.onload` event to fire *after* the `script.onload` has fired. So either the order of `script.onload` and `window.onload` is not guaranteed to be in a specific order or JSDOM has a bug. It would help to know which one it is.

Comment: doesn't replicate: https://repl.it/@mihaifm/jsdom ,  which version of jsdom are you using?

Comment: @mihai I am using jsdom 11.11.0. You are right. This was an issue in an older version of jsdom. This is no longer an issue in the most recent version.

Comment: @LoneLearner yes, I've added this as an answer, seems like a clear bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in JSDOM.

It appears to be solved in the latest version `13.0.0`, try updating JSDOM.

I've tried out the same code for [jsdom 13](https://repl.it/@mihaifm/jsdom) and it works.

```
window not available yet
script loaded
window loaded
```

while [jsdom 11](https://repl.it/@mihaifm/jsdom-1) indeed shows the problem:

```
window not available yet
window loaded
script loaded
```